# Server sending RST message immediately after client hello on load testing

Tags: java, sockets, openssl, tls1.2, serversocket

We are facing intermittent TLS handshake issue while connecting from a C++ (OpenSSL) client to a Java Server (Java 7). The issue is observed on load test after having around 100 session sending concurrent requests, that too on linux platform. Server is sending RST message immediately after "Client Hello" message.  On client side the SSL_CTX object is created with TLSv1_2_client_method(). On server side the the context instance is created by invoking SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"). Also we are limiting the enabled protocol to TLSv1.2 on server side. Whenever this issue is observed we have noticed that Client Hello Protocol on Wireshark as "TLSv1", in all other cases the Client Hello Protocol is displayed as TLSv1.2.

Also I understand the Handshake layer version number is important and any TLS1.2 compliant server MUST accept any value {03,XX} as the record layer version number for ClientHello as per RFC5246. But whenever the failure is observed, record layer is *"**TLSv1** Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello"*. In the case of successful handshake the record layer is "***TLSv1.2*** Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello".

The client hello message failure case:

```html
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 358
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 354
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 44e153eb9aa960e39e7dd4c01fbc1cc3770d95e0d70d6aac…
                GMT Unix Time: Aug 15, 2006 10:26:11.000000000 India Standard Time
                Random Bytes: 9aa960e39e7dd4c01fbc1cc3770d95e0d70d6aac83f458ab…
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 228
            Cipher Suites (114 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a5)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a3)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a1)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0069)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0068)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0037)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0036)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0087)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0086)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0085)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc019)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a7)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x003a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0089)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc02a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc026)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a4)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a0)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0098)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0097)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0044)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0043)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0042)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc018)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a6)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x006c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0034)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0046)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0018)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc002)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0010)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc017)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x001b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0015)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x000f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x000c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x001a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0019)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5 (0x0006)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0017)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 85
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 4
                EC point formats Length: 3
                Elliptic curves point formats (3)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
                    EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_prime (1)
                    EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_char2 (2)
            Extension: supported_groups (len=28)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 28
                Supported Groups List Length: 26
                Supported Groups (13 groups)
                    Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                    Supported Group: brainpoolP512r1 (0x001c)
                    Supported Group: brainpoolP384r1 (0x001b)
                    Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Supported Group: brainpoolP256r1 (0x001a)
                    Supported Group: secp256k1 (0x0016)
                    Supported Group: sect571r1 (0x000e)
                    Supported Group: sect571k1 (0x000d)
                    Supported Group: sect409k1 (0x000b)
                    Supported Group: sect409r1 (0x000c)
                    Supported Group: sect283k1 (0x0009)
                    Supported Group: sect283r1 (0x000a)
            Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
                Type: session_ticket (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=32)
                Type: signature_algorithms (13)
                Length: 32
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 30
                Signature Hash Algorithms (15 algorithms)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA512 DSA (0x0602)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA384 DSA (0x0502)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA256 DSA (0x0402)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 RSA (0x0301)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 DSA (0x0302)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 ECDSA (0x0303)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA1 DSA (0x0202)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_sha1 (0x0203)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
            Extension: heartbeat (len=1)
                Type: heartbeat (15)
                Length: 1
                Mode: Peer allowed to send requests (1)
```

The client hello message - successful case:

```html
Transport Layer Security
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
 Content Type: Handshake (22)
 Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
 Length: 358
 Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
  Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
  Length: 354
  Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
  Random: b2e7fe85a0e4403ae4fec4d698094b919375f9afed8efff4…
  Session ID Length: 0
  Cipher Suites Length: 228
  Cipher Suites (114 suites)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a5)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a3)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a1)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0069)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0068)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0037)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0036)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0087)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0086)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0085)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc019)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a7)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006d)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x003a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0089)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc032)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02e)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc02a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc026)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a4)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a0)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003f)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003e)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0031)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0030)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0098)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0097)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0044)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0043)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0042)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc018)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a6)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x006c)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0034)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009b)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0046)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc016)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0018)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc002)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0010)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000d)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc017)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x001b)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0015)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0012)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x000f)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x000c)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x001a)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0009)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0014)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0011)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0019)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0008)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5 (0x0006)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0017)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)
   Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
  Compression Methods Length: 1
  Compression Methods (1 method)
   Compression Method: null (0)
  Extensions Length: 85
  Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
   Type: ec_point_formats (11)
   Length: 4
   EC point formats Length: 3
   Elliptic curves point formats (3)
    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
    EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_prime (1)
    EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_char2 (2)
  Extension: supported_groups (len=28)
   Type: supported_groups (10)
   Length: 28
   Supported Groups List Length: 26
   Supported Groups (13 groups)
    Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
    Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
    Supported Group: brainpoolP512r1 (0x001c)
    Supported Group: brainpoolP384r1 (0x001b)
    Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
    Supported Group: brainpoolP256r1 (0x001a)
    Supported Group: secp256k1 (0x0016)
    Supported Group: sect571r1 (0x000e)
    Supported Group: sect571k1 (0x000d)
    Supported Group: sect409k1 (0x000b)
    Supported Group: sect409r1 (0x000c)
    Supported Group: sect283k1 (0x0009)
    Supported Group: sect283r1 (0x000a)
  Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
   Type: session_ticket (35)
   Length: 0
   Data (0 bytes)
  Extension: signature_algorithms (len=32)
   Type: signature_algorithms (13)
   Length: 32
   Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 30
   Signature Hash Algorithms (15 algorithms)
    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA512 DSA (0x0602)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA384 DSA (0x0502)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA256 DSA (0x0402)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 RSA (0x0301)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 DSA (0x0302)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 ECDSA (0x0303)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
    Signature Algorithm: SHA1 DSA (0x0202)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_sha1 (0x0203)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
     Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
  Extension: heartbeat (len=1)
   Type: heartbeat (15)
   Length: 1
   Mode: Peer allowed to send requests (1)
```

Note that the cipher suites and signature algorithm are same in both the cases. Since the issue occurs only under load in Linux, is there anyway we can increase the number of connection in Java or through any settings in Linux

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your decodes for _both_ cases show record-level 0x0301=TLS1.0 and clienthello 0x0303=TLS1.2, which is what OpenSSL client does (since 1.0.1), so I don't understand why Wireshark is summarizing them differently. And Java never RSTs initially; it sends alert and then closes which sends FIN, and only if another packet arrives after FIN the _OS_ sends RST. I would suspect something network level like a firewall, WAF, IDS/IPS, DLP. Are the clients on the same machine or one other machine or several? Where is(are) the capture(s) done? Is(are) the machine(s) virtual?

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your inputs. We have observed this error irrespective of whether the client and server on same machine or on two different machines. These are the captures from the client machines. On server side dump also we can observe client hello with same details. These are not virtual machines. One more recent observation, if we are using windows client then server is sending ACK message for client hello, but there is no further communication. Where as in Linux as mentioned in the question server is sending RST.

Comment: As per https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201701/msg00004.html SSL session version is based on not just the client hello but also the server hello. TLS 1.0 will be used either the server's response was not seen or responded that. In our case server sending RST that might be the reason Wireshark is showing TLSv1.

Comment: Is 'server side dump' network level? Does it show RST or FIN or what? I will be totally astonished if Linux server is _sending_ RST, and pretty surprised if _Java_ server on Windows is doing so. Can you run the server with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` and get its output, which will be voluminous and tedious to de-thread, but should show what the server thinks it is doing? Good catch on wireshark!

Comment: Hi Dave, Server side also was showing RST. We will try with debug level ssl:handshake. Thanks for your response. Also one more question since this happens on load test is there anything I can monitor to get to know server is hitting its max limit.